# Why it is possible to redefine err in multiple return statement in Go

Tags: go, variable-assignment

Consider the following example illustrating the question (it was just built to explain the question, but I saw similar code in books as well in real projects):

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    n1, err := strconv.Atoi("1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("%v", err)
    }

    n2, err := strconv.Atoi("2")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("%v", err)
    }

    // err := fmt.Errorf("new error") <- line 1

    // n1, err := strconv.Atoi("3") <- line 2

    fmt.Printf("n1 = %d, n2 = %d\n", n1, n2)
}
```

The compiler doesn't complain about redefining `err`, but if I uncomment `<- line 1` or `<- line 2`, it will complain `no new variable on left side of :=`.

So, how does it work? Why the compiler happily allows to override `err` in multi return statement, using `:=`, but not `n1` on `<- line 2` example?

Better if you can point into the official reference explaining this behavior.

Comment: Well, I almost finished http://www.gopl.io/ (although focused on data type, methods, interfaces, concurrency), and read effective go, and other resources (although usually the topics I am interested in the moment), I've used Go for algorithmic competitions, as well building CLI tool. I mean reading a doc is a good thing, but it is much better building things and while building learning a language, for me it is a balance, between time spending on learning vs building (having a result) things. Especially when you start leaning a new language, you want to see the results to keep it going.

Comment: And when I talk about CLI, I mean using crypto/ssh/net/http/base64/yaml and other packages, as well as go-bindata :), just as overall overview :)

Comment: But, thank you for mentioning this in the effective go doc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is because you used [Short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) `:=`. Quoting from the spec:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may *redeclare* variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-[blank](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) variables is new. As a consequence, **redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration**. Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

This line:

```
n1, err := strconv.Atoi("1")
```

Is a multi-variable short declaration, and all variables on the left side are new, and so all will be declared (and return values of `strconv.Atoi()` assigned).

This line:

```
n2, err := strconv.Atoi("2")
```

It is a multi-variable short declaration, and `n2` is new. So it declares `n2` and only assigns a new value to `err`, because `err` is already declared in the same block.

This line:

```
err := fmt.Errorf("new error") <- line 1
```

It is **not** a multi-variable short declaration. It would try to declare `err` but it is already declared in the same block, therefore it is a compile-time error.

And this line:

```
n1, err := strconv.Atoi("3") <- line 2
```

It is a multi-variable short declaration, but **all the variables** on the left side have been **previously declared** in the same block, so it is also a compile-time error (it doesn't introduce any new variables on the left side).

Note that if all the variables on the left side have been previously declared, simply changing from Short variable declaration `:=` to [Assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) `=` will make it work (assumed values on the right side are [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the variables on the left side).

Answer (score 0):

Check the section "Redeclaration and reassignment" in this official document https://go.dev/doc/effective_go.